# Get value from div with javascript: Always get undefined

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

I had this problem when I get the value from a div:

```
function sync(){
    var n1 = document.getElementById('editor').value;
    alert(n1);
    var n2 = document.getElementById('news');
    n2.value = n1;
}
```

div with id `editor` looks like this:

```
<div class='message'  id='editor' contenteditable="true" onkeyUp='sync()' style="color: black"></div>
```

When I put something in that div it will alert me undefined and that will also come in the textarea i paste it in too. So the problem is obviously by this:

```
var n1 = document.getElementById('editor').value;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with jquery.. Use following script.. $('#editor').text()

Comment: We use `document.getElementById('elementid').value;` for input fields. In your case it is a **DIV**, So you should use **innerHTML** or **innerText**.
`var n1 = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
var n1 = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML; // or innerText, or textContent
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's important to note that even if `<div>` was a HTMLInputElement you would still keep getting undefined because your div,

```
<div class='message'  id='editor' contenteditable="true" onkeyUp='sync()' style="color: black"></div>
```

Has no value attribute, here is an example of a div with a value attribute:

```
<div class='message'  id='editor' value='hello'></div>
```

However, as mentioned in other answers, even though you have entered a value it, .value will still return undefined because `<div>` is a HTML element and not a HTMLInputElement.

If you really need to store some information in the value of the div you can always do something like this:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>document.getElementById('mydiv').value='hello';</script>
```

Right after the div loads, you force 'hello' as the value.

The only reason you'd do this is if you really want to store data within the div's value and can't store it within the innerHTML because the div is visible.

If you want to store the information within your div like this:

```
<div id="editor">all the information i want to store</div>
```

Then `document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;`  is the correct solution, but remember that users will be able to see the information on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Elements and HTMLInputElements are different things.

The `value` attribute is present in HTMLInputElement in [HTMLInputElement Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

`div` elements are `HTMLElement`

If you change your `div` to input your `Javascript` will work fine.

The option is to use `innerHTML` as said in another answer but be aware that this could be HTML fragment at times if you don't control the HTML or over time forget the Javascript and can lead to defects as things.

FYI plain  [elements attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)(there is no `value`)