# Javascript: Hide element if condition is met

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide an element based on its ID, but, I haven't been able to get it to work. I've Googled the answer but, no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to work for me.

My code is attached below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- HTML -->
    <body>
        <div id="role" value="Edit">
            <button> Edit </button>
        </div>
    </body>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script>
        if(document.getElementById("role").value == 'Edit'){
            document.getElementById("role").style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please ask clear question, when you want to hide, on button click?

or what exactly you wants?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131899/get-value-from-div-with-javascript-always-get-undefined/36759120 - according to this, the
document.getElementById("role").value can only be used if this would be an input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below, you want to get an attribute and not the value.

You can use querySelector instead of getElementById if you want.

```js
var role = document.querySelector('#role');

if(role.getAttribute('value') == 'Edit'){
    role.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- HTML -->
    <body>
        <div id="role" value="Edit">
            <button> Edit </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works! I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- HTML -->
<body>
    <div id="role" value="Edit">
        <button> Edit </button>
    </div>
</body>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
    if(document.getElementById("role").getAttribute('value') == 'Edit'){
        document.getElementById("role").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `document.getElementById("role").value` is undefined. To retrieve an attribute value you should use `element.getAttribute('attr')` method or `element.attributes[attr].value`.

In your case it would be `document.getElementById("role").attributes['value'].value`