# Can't get the value of input element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to format the value from an input field but I cant get the value

following is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="search" />
    <button id="btn" onclick="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

And here is JS code:

```
var searchValue = document.querySelector('#search').value;

function search() {
    console.log(searchValue);
}
```

Running that code logs empty value but if I remove the .value from querySelector line and use it as

`console.log(searchValue.value)`;

then it works

What is the problem here!?

Comment: `searchValue` is set only once, when the input value is still empty

Comment: `document.querySelector('#search').value` returns the value at the moment of execution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get value from div with javascript: Always get undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131899/get-value-from-div-with-javascript-always-get-undefined)

Comment: Your question shows HTML and Javascript code, but isn't a brief complete file. One can't see how the Javascript is triggered and that is crucial as the previous comments mentioned (including another Andreas). You need to read the value after it's set. What you are doing is reading the searchValue (obviously at startup when empty) and reading that empty value somewhat later. What you should do is using the variable as a bookmark like `var searchValue = document.querySelector('#search');` and retrieve the bookmark's value later. That is why using .value later works just as you experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal you set you variable `searchValue` outside of your function `search()` called on click.

Set your variable inside your function called on click.

If you get the value at a moment it has no value it is normal you get no value.

So if you get the value outside of your click function you won't have it. You must use .value at the moment you have a value.

```js
function search() {
    var searchValue = document.getElementById('search').value;
    console.log(searchValue);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="search" />
    <button id="btn" onclick="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Here as you can see we can read the value, because it has one at the time I am asking for. Above you set the value "in theory" after you clicked.

```js
var searchValue = document.getElementById('search').value;
console.log(searchValue);

function search() {
    console.log(searchValue);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="search" value="TEST"/>
    <button id="btn"  onclick="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: OP knows that this works: _"but if I remove the .value from querySelector line and use it as `console.log(searchValue.value);` then it works"_

Comment: @crg Yeah! Thanks!! This was the problem, now its working!!

Comment: Glad my answer helped. If it solve you problem check it has answered, it will let the community know that this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You only update `searchValue` once when the page is loaded. At this time your text field still contains nothing (strictly an empty string) which is loaded into `searchValue`.

I assume you want to load it each time your button is clicked, so you need to do this inside `search` as demonstrated in the example.

```js
function search() {
  //Load the value from the text field each time we need it
  let searchValue = document.getElementById("search").value;
  //Log the value in console
  console.log(searchValue);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="search" />
    <button id="btn" onclick="search()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` is absolutely valid/standard JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: @Detonar I tried using getElementById but that wasn't the problem, I mostly use querySelector with no problems

Comment: @user1599011 - Thanks, adapte the answer.

Comment: @SEKTION - Yes, your more obvious problem is that you load the variable outside of your event handler. This is only executes once and that is when the page is loaded. You need to do this inside `search` as this answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
function find()
{
serchValue = document.getElementById("search").value;
console.log(searchValue);
}
```